# Mobile : Flights listing getting stucked in mobile browser

Tags: php, android, xml, html, mustache

1. We are developing a mobile site in which we are displaying the flights.
2. We are doing XML parsing before rendering the data using mustache.js,php(laravel 4), laravel memcache.

**Issue**

- Flight listing in web browser is faster than mobile.
- Mobile browser freezes before rendering the data.

  Any tips to render data fastly in mobile browsers.

Comment: Use Asynktask to load data & then display display it.

Comment: can u pls tell in detail, will that work in php

Comment: For android you are using webview to display the content of the side.
So,first fetch the data on doInbackground

Answer (score 0):

If you added any image in that page . Reduce the image size

Comment: there are no big images, only thing is i am using flight images which is of kbs

Answer (score 0):

Such a list should run smoothly on any device. There must be some heavy loading that is taking place. Counter that. Perhaps, you wanna take some load off the list, item and see where the list feels relaxed.